# open source controls to convert rich text formatted code to html markup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rtf

I am working on asp.net mvc. I am trying to display the rich text formatted content like,

```
    {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\htmautsp\deff2{\fonttbl{\f0\
fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f2\fcharset0 Tahoma;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;}\loch\hi
ch\dbch\pard\plain\ltrpar\itap0{\lang1033\fs24\f2\cf0 \cf
0\ql{\f2 {\ltrch AMANDA WITH RC CALLED AND WANTED TO 
VERIFY THAT WE WERE AFFILIATED WITH SHAUN @ JAGGYS. LET HER KNOW WE 
WERE, SHAUN CALLED RC AS WELL TO VERIFY STATUS OF BD}\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
    }
    }
```

in the view. Actually this data could come from database table and i need to display it in the editor type control. so is there any open source controls that are able to display rich text format.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just got done writing a RTF to HTML converter that maintains all embedded media, and creates a MIME multipart message out of it. This is close to what you want to do. Essentially if you aren't interested in writing your own converter, you can look at this CodeProject and use his: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter 
There is also descriptions as to how to reach his solution.

On my project we just started ripping apart the RTF document and parsing its contents. Open source and 3rd-Party Libraries weren't an option for me.